# I tried programming with Python Pillow, but I don't get my output image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Following is the code and the output:

```
from PIL import Image

mac=open("example.jpg")

mac

win=open("pencils.jpg")

win
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try `Image.open`. Your code is using the default `open` method from Python which is used to open any file.

Comment: Thanks a ton, it worked. What is the reason the first method didn't work out?

Comment: You weren't using PIL's open method, you were using Python's generic open method which is used to read bytes and text